# Non-Latin tag link from the post body is broken in Android app

Tags: bug, tags, android-app, localization

Using non-Latin tag link from the post body leads to URL-encoded tag, which obviously is not exist on the site.

For instance, referencing from [this post](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/9033/176217) to the tag [метки] results with the following:

> [image]

- App Version: 1.0.95
- Device Manufacturer: LGE
- Device Model: LM-G710
- OS Version: 8.0.0 (190492326deb8.FGN)