# Background of "Edit tags" button overlaps with other tags

Tags: bug, design, responsive-design, inline-tag-editor

After the using of inline tag editor (tap "Edit tags", then cancel) on [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327639/339911) the "Edit tags" button background is overlapped with other tags:

> [image]

Image was taken from mobile Chrome with enabled responsiveness.